# How can a subclass override the mapping of an inherited association so that it is ignored (not mapped for the subclass entity)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

Given some entities like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id")
    private AnotherEntity friend;
}

@Entity
public class AnotherEntity {
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class ConcreteEntity extends BaseEntity {
    //...
}
```

How can `ConcreteEntity` override the mapping of `friend` so that it is not mapped at all for instances of `ConcreteEntity`?

Answer (score 0):

In general in an entity you can override (elements of) a relationship from a `@MappedSuperclass` using the `@AssociationOverrides` annotation, but what you want is to force ignoring it. For that there is the `@Transient` annotation, but which does not instruct the JPA provider to ignore the overridden property. So you have IMHO a single possibility: defining a SupperMappedClass without that relationship and use that in your class hierarchy:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntityWithoutFriend {

}


@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntityWithFriend {
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id")
    private AnotherEntity friend;
}


@Entity
public class ConcreteEntity extends BaseEntityWithoutFriend {//NOTE here that we extend the EntityWithoutFriend
    //...
}
```

NOTE: as of my experience with Hibernate, adding a property `@Transient AnotherEntity friend` in your entity will simply force mapping only MappedSupperClass friend property, ignoring only the property defined in `ConcreteEntity`.