# How to apply @OneToMany on super class getter method in multiple subclasses with different target entity

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0, one-to-many

**Stack**

I'm using JPA2.0 with Eclipselink 2.6.3 and Spring 4(JTA).

**Problem**

I'm trying to override the class A attribute with @OneToMany mapping in class B and class C (which is similar to class B ) so that I can change the target entity to class X and Z respectively while fetching results for class B.

Class A has SINGLE_TABLE inheritance and class B & C are discriminator classes which is maintained by @classExtractor depending on some field value in class A.

Class Z has TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance and class X & Y extends class Z with same table (just a hack for inheritance to avoid DTYPE).

**Expected Result**
When I query on class B or Class C and fetch getZList() then I should be able to see class X and Y type objects as mentioned in targetEntity in @OneToMany mapping in class B & C

I tried overriding the getter of class A in subclasses like below but the list is always empty.

Class A

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_A")
@Customizer(ACustomizer.class)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@ClassExtractor(AExtractor.class)
@InstantiationCopyPolicy
@Cacheable
@Cache( alwaysRefresh=true,
        refreshOnlyIfNewer=true,
        expiry=300000,      
        coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES)
public class A implements Serializable {
@Column(name="ABC")
private String abc;
@Transient
private List zlist= new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Class B

```
@Entity
public class B extends A{
//problem is here...this mappping doesn't populate super class object 
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="class A", targetEntity=Z.class)
    @PrivateOwned 
    public List getZList() {
        return super.getZList();
    }
}
```

Class Z

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_Z")
@Customizer(ZCustomizer.class)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Z{
 //some fields 
//and @oneToOne mapped with class A
}
```

class X

```
 @Table(name="TABLE_Z")
   @Entity
    public class X extends Z{
     //some fields 

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with  'mappedBy="class A"'?  It has nothing to do with overriding properties, and is used to tell JPA where the foreign key definition exists if the target class already defined its own ManyToOne relationship to this class

Comment: That said, what you are looking for doesn't seem possible.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762375/how-can-a-subclass-override-the-mapping-of-an-inherited-association-so-that-it-i

Comment: Hi Chris yes it looks impossible and weird situation as this is existing legacy architecture.Although I ran into a problem with my Class Z which has TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance. When I query on class A then the list is bringing same object three times like objects instance of X.Y & Z which is weird.Can u spot me whats going wrong ? Note ( Ihave remove @transient on list Z in class A and using oneToMany mapping

Comment: Inheritance might not be right for what you want to do, as it seems your subclasses are completely different and shouldn't share this mapping at all.  As for JPA bringing in the same row 3 times: you have table per class specified on Z and its children, but have X mapped to the same table.  JPA will look at Table_Z and build Z instances, then it will query Table_Z for X instances, and likely the same for Y.  I'm not sure what you are after, but this won't work.